# Konditional passiv

Tags: grammar, subjunctive, passive

I have problems constructing conditional mood from these German sentences. When I want to say, forexample, "The letter would have been written if ..." I would translate it as

> Der Brief wäre von mir geschrieben worden, wenn ...

However, Google translate suggests that this should be

> Der Brief wäre von mir geschrieben worden sein.

So how would these following sentences go with conditional mood?

```
The letter is (being) written by me. 
Der Brief wird von mir geschrieben.

The letter was written by me.
Der Brief wurde von mir geschrieben.

The letter has been written by me.
Der Brief ist von mir geschrieben worden.

The letter had been written by me.
Der Brief war von mir geschrieben worden.

The letter will be written by me.
Der Brief wird von mir geschrieben werden.

The letter will have been written by me.
Der Brief wird von mir geschrieben worden sein.
```

Comment: The last one "The letter will have been written by me" should be "Der Brief wird von mir geschrieben worden sein", because the Futur II is "werden geworden sein".

Comment: Please don't let Google confuse you - it just does not work for German. Never use it as a reference, actually not even for hints when it comes to grammar.

Answer (score 2):

There are three *Konjunktiv* forms in German: *Konjunktiv I*, *Konjunktiv II* and the *"würde"-Konjunktiv*. The main purpose of *Konjunktiv I* is in reported speech; you are asking for the conditional use: Here you have to take *Konjunktiv II* or the *"würde"-Konjunktiv*. (I'm listing the *Konjunktiv I* forms just for completeness.)

The main verb in your sentence is *(geschrieben) werden*; its *Konjunktiv* forms in present tense are:

> **Indikativ:** Der Brief wird von mir geschrieben.
>   (**Konjunktiv I:** Der Brief werde von mir geschrieben.)
>   **Konjunktiv II:** Der Brief würde von mir geschrieben.
>   **"würde"-Konjunktiv:** Der Brief würde von mir geschrieben werden.

There are no distinct *Konjunktiv* forms for the various past tenses:

> **Indikativ:** Der Brief wurde von mir geschrieben.
>   **Indikativ:** Der Brief ist von mir geschrieben worden.
>   **Indikativ:** Der Brief war von mir geschrieben worden.
>   (**Konjunktiv I:** Der Brief sei von mir geschrieben worden.)
>   **Konjunktiv II:** Der Brief wäre von mir geschrieben worden.
>   **"würde"-Konjunktiv:** Der Brief würde von mir geschrieben worden sein.

The *"würde"-Konjunktiv* of future tense is very unaesthetic; so take the *Konjunktiv II* here:

> **Indikativ:** Der Brief wird von mir geschrieben werden.
>   (**Konjunktiv I:** Der Brief werde von mir geschrieben werden.)
>   **Konjunktiv II:** Der Brief würde von mir geschrieben werden.
>   (**"würde"-Konjunktiv:** Der Brief würde von mir geschrieben werden werden.)

As you can see, the future *Konjunktiv II* form collides with the present *"würde"-Konjunktiv*. The *Konjunktiv* forms of future perfect are:

> **Indikativ:** Der Brief wird von mir geschrieben worden sein.
>   (**Konjunktiv I:** Der Brief werde von mir geschrieben worden sein.)
>   **Konjunktiv II:** Der Brief würde von mir geschrieben worden sein.
>   **"würde"-Konjunktiv:** Der Brief würde von mir geschrieben worden sein werden.

However, in this last case the *"würde"-Konjunktiv* is very hard to parse because of the numerous auxiliaries.

Answer (score 1):

In German, the conditional mood is expressed by the subjunctive II, so the answers should be the following:

> Der Brief wird von mir geschrieben.
> Der Brief würde von mir geschrieben.
>
> Der Brief wurde von mir geschrieben.
> Der Brief wäre von mir geschrieben worden.
>
> Der Brief ist von mir geschrieben worden.
> Der Brief wäre von mir geschrieben worden.
>
> Der Brief war von mir geschrieben worden.
> Der Brief wäre von mir geschrieben worden.
>
> Der Brief wird von mir geschrieben werden.
> Der Brief würde von mir geschrieben werden.
>
> Der Brief wird von mir geschrieben worden sein.
> Der Brief würde von mir geschrieben worden sein.

As you can see, the subjunctive II has only one past tense, not three, like the indicative.